# typescript parameter of type anonymous class

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a class as parameter:

```js
function extendClass(cls = class {}) {
  return class extends cls {
    constructor () {
      super();
      console.log("I extend " + cls.name);
    }
  };
}
```

I want to remove the default value of the parameter `cls` and make it required.

What type should the parameter `cls` have?

Comment: It could be something like `new () => object` but I don't know that this will be strongly typed enough for your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of modifying the code you provided based on support for mix-in classes as mentioned [TypeScript 2.2 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/release%20notes/TypeScript%202.2.md).

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function extendClass<Class extends Constructor<{}>>(cls: Class) {
    return class extends cls {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            console.log("I extend " + cls.name);
        }
    };
}

// Valid example:
class Test {
    constructor() { }
}

const ExtendedClass = extendClass(Test)
new ExtendedClass()

// Invalid examples:
extendClass("a")
extendClass(1)
extendClass({})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=16#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAKEkAzdAmwBLRFAgAPYBAQATGABsmSJHn2GkqjVu3n4yNFhz4A3gF8iRWpj2dYBoyKdJKGCoVAhgdFQEKC8zC00dcy9zQJC0mMQUDGxcBmY2Hx5+YShU9PKkdEhUPPoWdiEpcvLMTLg9CHo9OFZaACIASXirKD6oAGoY73oEJgBbCEag5pdl4JcpVckAem2oADUmPUVtC3mwDo5JWKMoAggUUrWMu2zHWgCoVa3WuygAUUsOgguj85nI6gSoLMtHuKCEkkoNEBUJBpiMH2kuygAwQADcjicznMLg8rpCrOikP0mH0ERSdFTaABGelA6EY1xCIA)

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly! but I'm not sure to understand this: `Constructor<{}>` can you explain it?

Comment: `{}` is the value for `T`. Where `T` is the generic that represents the return value of a classes' constructor. So this is saying that the input classes constructor returns `{}`